# Python Shell How to Update Status in Shell Without Newline

Tags: python, shell

Perhaps its not even possible, **but how do you get the shell to update a program's status (such as a countdown) without causing a newline?**

Normally it would be 
5
4
3
2
1

But I'd rather it just stay in place, such as I've seen in running other shell programs.
Better yet, if there was a sub-method I could employ which gave a nice table-layout like mysql...or the `top` program.

I've tried `print "countdown \c"` and other similar things, but I've not found any effective way to do this.

Comment: it would be OS dependant ... but the curses library is one thing you should look at ...

Comment: Thanks will look into that...I'm on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `'\r'` at the end to return to the beginning, and include a comma to avoid a newline:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i, '\r',
    time.sleep(1)
```

On some systems, you'll need to flush the `stdout` like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i, '\r',
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm on ubuntu ... this is a separate function call, seems to do newlines still...I'll toy around with this concept though.

Comment: @Orangeman555, edited with a solution that works on my mac and pc. presumably if it works on the mac it'll work on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
import time
print "Countdown"

for i in range(5,-1,-1):
              print "\b\b%d"%i,  #\b means backspace
              time.sleep(1)
```

but really unless this is all you want to do you should look into something like curses  (or a gui of some sort)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\r` character, to do:

```
for i in range(0,100):
   print i, '\r',
```